# VB 6: How do I find the area inside a form?

Tags: vb6

In VB 6 I'm trying to make a control automatically resize based on the form's size. Unfortunately Form.Width is the total width of the form, not just the client area. So how do I find out the interior heigth and width?

Comment: This was a problem I fought with for a while - I don't have the code with me right now, but I'll post my solution as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight property.

Comment: Duh, I can't believe I didn't remember that.